# How to detect whether circle is translated in clockwise or not in d3

Tags: d3.js

I am using globe functionality using d3 and d3 geo zoom library.

Almost all things are done, but having one issue.

I have draw circle with element g, it is rotating along with path when we rotate globe, but main problem is that element g should be hide when path goes behind, right now points are showing when path goes behind while rotating, so what would the best solution to hide points on globe when map path is behind.

```
      var zoom = d3.geo.zoom()
     .projection(projection)
    .scaleExtent([minScale, maxScale])
     .on("zoomstart", function() {
        // TODO inertial drag
        if (d3.event.sourceEvent) svg.selectAll("path").classed("focus", false);      
    })
    .on("zoom",function() {
        if (d3.event.sourceEvent) {
          d3.event.sourceEvent.preventDefault();
        }
        d3.select(this).call(redraw);
        suppressClick = true;   

    })
    .on("zoomend", function() {
    svg.classed("zooming", false);
    });
    function redraw(svg) {
  svg.selectAll('path')
    .attr('d', function (d) {
      var g = d3.select(this);
      return path.pointRadius(g.classed('focus') || g.classed('focus-hover') ? 9.5 : 7.5)(d);
    });

  var cluster = svg.selectAll('g.cluster')
    .each(function (d) {
      d.projected = null;         
      d3.geo.stream(d, projection.stream({point: function (x, y) {
        d.projected = [x, y];
      }}));

      var circle = d3.select(this).select('circle.cluster');
      circle.attr('r', circle.classed('focus-hover') ? 9.5 : 8.5);
    })
    .attr('transform', function (d) {
      return 'translate(' + (d.projected || 0) + ')';
    });     
    g.selectAll('g.cluster').attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + projection([d[1],d[0]]) + ")";});
    /*.style('display', function (d) {
      return d.projected ? null : 'none';
    })
    .attr('transform', function (d) {
      return 'translate(' + (d.projected || 0) + ')';
    });*/

  var displayLocation = projection.scale() > maxScale - 0.1;
  svg.classed('zoomed', displayLocation);

  if (displayLocation) {
    cluster.selectAll('.location')
      .style('display', null)
      .attr('r', function (d) {
        var circle = d3.select(this);
        return circle.classed('focus') || circle.classed('focus-hover') ? 9.5 : 7.5;
      });
    cluster.selectAll('.label').style('display', null);
  } else {
    cluster.selectAll('.location').style('display', 'none');
    cluster.selectAll('.label').style('display', 'none');
  }
}
```

Comment: code of what you have done so far ?

Comment: Here is my link: http://projectsdemo.net/globe/v4/
In which when I rotate points are still showing when it goes behind while rotating.

Comment: var zoom = d3.geo.zoom()
   .projection(projection)
  .scaleExtent([minScale, maxScale])
   .on("zoomstart", function() {
   // TODO inertial drag
   if (d3.event.sourceEvent) svg.selectAll("path").classed("focus", false);   
  })
  .on("zoom",function() {
   if (d3.event.sourceEvent) {
     d3.event.sourceEvent.preventDefault();
   }
   d3.select(this).call(redraw);
   suppressClick = true;   
   
  })
  .on("zoomend", function() {
  svg.classed("zooming", false);
  });
  
 g.call(zoom);

Comment: on zoom function I have called function redraw, which contains following code

Comment: Please, edit your question with the code, don't put the code in the comments.

Comment: Here is my JS: http://projectsdemo.net/globe/v4/js/globe.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to *hide* them. Set CSS `display` to `none` when they appear behind the globe, that is, when any of their positions is not in the range `[-90,90]` for latitude or longitude).

You can add the *yaw* and *pitch* angles obtained from [projection.rotate()](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Geo-Projections.md#rotate) (which are, respectively, equivalent to *longitude* and *latitude*) to each corresponding longitude/latitude coordinate of the circle. If the result is out of range hide it (`display: none`), otherwise show it (`display:block`). You can start with like this:

```
d3.selectAll("circle").style("display", function(d) {
    return d[0] + projection.rotate()[0] < 90
        && d[0] + projection.rotate()[0] > -90
        && d[1] + projection.rotate()[1] < 90
        && d[1] + projection.rotate()[1] > -90  ? "block" : "none";
})
```

Comment: Hello Thank you very much for your solution its working.
But I am facing small issue.
Circle is not getting hide on edge of globe from left to right and top to bottom.

Could you please check below link and share your view with us
http://projectsdemo.net/globe/v4/